# Android how to clearAnimation?

Tags: android, animation

Trying out the android-TNRAnimationHelper animation library
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4572#!description

Pulse Animation

```
    PulseAnimation.create().with(pulseImage)
        .setDuration(310)
        .setRepeatCount(PulseAnimation.INFINITE)
        .setRepeatMode(PulseAnimation.REVERSE)
        .start();
```

Trying to cancel using:

```
    findViewById(R.id.my_view).clearAnimation();
```

This doesn't stop the animation.

How can I clear an animation from a view/image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop an animation you have to set the `Animation` on the `View` to null.

In your case

```
pulseImage.setAnimation(null);
```

Comment: This indeed is the way, it seems no matter what I do this animation does not clear.(seems like a bug)